# TImage saves my PNG image with transparency as JPEG after sharing in Delphi XE8

Tags: png, jpeg, transparency, delphi-xe8, timage

I assign a PNG image with transparency to the TImage component in Delphi XE8, used the sharesheet action to share this image. The successful result on my smartphone is now a JPEG image which loses all the transparency obviously. My transparent background now becomes black.

I need my images to retain its transparency, what do I do?

Here's my code:

```
var
ShareSheetForm: TShareSheetForm;



implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}


    procedure TShareSheetForm.ShowShareSheetAction1BeforeExecute(Sender: TObject);

begin


    ShowShareSheetAction1.Bitmap.Assign(Image1.Bitmap);

end;


end.
```

Comment: JPEG doesn't do transparency. How do you share this image exactly?

Comment: @Pekka I didn't share a JPEG image, I shared a PNG image with transparency. After I share this to an IM on my mobile device, it is automatically converted to a JPEG image. I have no clue why it does that. I'm trying to stop it.

Comment: Hmm, what technology, what protocol is used for the sharing?

Comment: @Pekka here is a demonstration of how it works [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/User:Maria/Mobile_Tutorial:_Taking_and_Sharing_a_Picture,_and_Sharing_Text_(iOS_and_Android))